# Add Elements dynamically to The XAML page in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, dynamic, textblock

I'm new to WP7 and I want to know if there is any way to add items like a TextBlock to 
a page dynamically using the .cs part??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock();
// set some properties
YourMainContainer.Children.Add(textBlock); //
```

If you need more details just comment this

Comment: where exactly do you specify what `YourMainContainer` is

Answer (score 1):

If you know the controls that you'd like to appear on the page dynamically, then I'd approach the problem by including those controls in the XAML and using the Visibility property on the controls to show and hide them. In Silverlight, the Visibility enumeration is limited to the values Visible and Collapsed, so when it isn't visible the it doesn't take up any space. You can control Visibility with data-binding by using a converter (search on "visibility bind converter") if you are intersted in pursuing that avenue. You can show/hide groups of controls by changing the Visibility of their parent control, such as StackPanel or custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
                    TextBlock txtmsg = new TextBlock();
                    txtmsg.Text = "New Program.";                               
                    txtmsg.Margin = new Thickness(10, 20, 10, 10);
                    txtmsg.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                    txtmsg.FontSize = 28;
                    txtmsg.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                    ContentPanel.Children.Add(txtmsg);
```